# Android Ratingbar in dialog different screen size issue

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have a rating bar in a dialog. I have set maximum stars to **6**. The code below works fine on smartphones with small screen size. However, when tested on a tablet (10 inch), I see **11** starts and the layout wraps the content. Why this weird behavior happens? and how to fix it?

```
public void ShowDialog()
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(this);
        rating.setMax(6);

        popDialog.setTitle("Vote!! ");
        popDialog.setView(rating);

        // Button OK
        popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        txtView.setText(String.valueOf(rating.getProgress()));
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                })

        // Button Cancel
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        popDialog.create();
        popDialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation,

> The number of stars set (via setNumStars(int) or in an XML layout) will be shown when the layout width is set to wrap content (if another layout width is set, the results may be unpredictable).

Also, you should use `setNumStars()` to set the number of stars, rather than `setMax()`.

Layout width attribute is set over your rating bar, by calling `setLayoutParams()`:

```
        ratingBar.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I tried setNumStars() as well, it does not fix the issue. How the layout width is set to wrap content in a dialog?